# pass list of strings to fabric task

Tags: python, fabric

I'd like to pass a list of strings to a fabric task as an argument.  For instance, for the following fabfile:

```
def test(names):
  print names
```

I would like to pass "fab test:[tom, dick, harry]" and have the list print out.

Is this possible to do in fabric by default, or do I need to pass a string and split it myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

One way would be to use positional args:

```
@task
def mytask(*args):
    print args
```

Then calling it this way:

```
$ fab mytask:foo,bar,baz
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Note that you get the arguments as a tuple, not a list, but this should not make a big difference.

If this does not work for you and you need something more fancy, you'll probably have to parse the arguments yourself.

See: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments

Answer (score 5):

Fabric seems to always expand lists or tuples into individual arguments, so here's what I do:

```
def test(names):
    if isinstance(names, basestring):
        names = names.split(";")
    for name in names:
        # do something for every name...
```

That way, programmatically, I can still pass a list or tuple of names to this function, and for testing purposes, I can specify them on the command line as a string delimited by semicolons:

```
fab -f fabfile.py test:'tom;dick;harry'
```